# Pass generic parameter optionally?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following `NetworkUseCase` interface which processes a network request. `P` is the type of `requestData` and `R` the type of `responseData`.

```
interface NetworkUseCase<in P, out R> {
    fun process(requestData: P) : R
}
```

The way it is normally used is the following:

```
class ConcreteUseCase : NetworkUseCase<ConcreteRequestData, ConcreteResponseData> {
    override fun process(requestData: ConcreteRequestData): ConcreteResponseData {
        ...
    }
}

// It is called like this
val responseData = ConcreteUseCase().process(requestData)
```

However, there are some use cases where there are **no requestData needed**. In that case, there should be no requestData argument passed. But I am not sure how to achieve that.

```
val responseData = ConcreteUseCase().process()
```

What I have done so far is to set the type of requestData to Unit but then I still need to pass Unit as a parameter:

```
class ConcreteUseCase : NetworkUseCase<Unit, ConcreteResponseData> {
    override fun process(requestData: Unit): ConcreteResponseData {
        ...
    }
}

// It is called like this
val responseData = ConcreteUseCase().process(Unit)
```

Is there a way to achieve not being forced to always pass an argument in `process()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an extension function to overload it so any concrete version that uses `Unit` for the first type would automatically have access to this simpler overload:

```
fun <T> NetworkUseCase<Unit, T>.process() = process(Unit)
```

But if the number of arguments for the function are not always the same, why put this function in an interface at all?  You wouldn't be able to use it in an abstract way.

Comment: I would have preferred if the solution was built in with generics (Diego Marin solution) but unfortunately this would mean I need to always pass nullable objects in `process()`. In that case, I think this is the most convenient solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need a nullable input type with a default value

```
interface NetworkUseCase<in P, out R> {
    fun process(requestData: P? = null) : R
}

class ConcreteUseCase : NetworkUseCase<ConcreteRequestData, ConcreteResponseData> {
    override fun process(requestData: ConcreteRequestData?): ConcreteResponseData {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it like that:

```
val responseData = ConcreteUseCase().process()
```

**EDIT:**

This solution is gonna work just fine when it is necessary to pass a parameter to the process function:

```
val resquestData: ConcreteRequestData = ...
ConcreteUseCase().process(resquestData)
```

It is due to the fact that a non-nullable type is a subtype of its correposding nullable one.

**EDIT 2:**

Revisiting this answer I realized that the concrete use case may always have no parameter expected. The interface still works and the concrete class should be like that:

```
class ConcreteUseCase : NetworkUseCase<Unit, ConcreteResponseData> {
    override fun process(requestData: Unit?): ConcreteResponseData {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be a great solution if it weren't for the fact that now I am forced to always pass nullable parameters in concrete use cases `process()`. Would there be any way to avoid that?

Comment: You are not forced to pass nullable parameters. Non-nullable types inherent from their corresponding nullable one.

Comment: My mistake, I meant the parameter type `requestData` in `ConcreteUseCase` must be nullable (`RequestData?`). Even though I wouldn't pass null values, I would like to have compile safety.

Comment: It has to be nullable cause its default value is `null` when it is not provided.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to create a `NoRequestData` class and set that object as a default parameter? I tried it unsuccessfully.

Comment: Well, afaik an Interface is a specification of a behavior that needs to be implemented. If you want to express the fact that request data parameter doesn't always need to be provided, in my view, the way it should be done is defining it, in the interface, as a nullable parameter with default value `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a type alias for a `NetworkUseCase` without request data:

```
typealias NoRequestDataNetworkUseCase<R> = NetworkUseCase<Unit, R>
```

and add an extension function to the type alias like [@Tenfour04 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62066863/8167493).

```
fun <T> NoRequestDataNetworkUseCase<T>.process() = process(Unit)
```

so you will use it like this:

```
class ConcreteUseCase : NoRequestDataNetworkUseCase<ConcreteResponseData> {
    override fun process(requestData: Unit): ConcreteResponseData {
        // ...
    }
}

// It is called like this
val responseData = ConcreteUseCase().process()
```

But I also think is better to define a different abstraction for network use cases that doesn't need request data.

```
interface NoRequestDataNetworkUseCase<out R> {
    fun process() : R
}
```

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately not feasible due to the structure of the existing project.